# how to test anything on zdefre asdf awe?

Tags: graphql

as a newbie I took sample code and try to change it. like this

```
int 'response:', response
```

and im getting this error:

"errors" : [ {
"message" : "Unable to parse GraphQL query.",
"errorType" : "MalformedHttpRequestException"
} ]

could someone suggest me what im doing wrong?

**Edit**

Now I tried to remove /graphql from the url the test is passing but in response im getting this:

```
04:45:36.321 [print] response: {
  "Version": "1.0",
  "Output": {
    "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be typo, a `:` after `Given` ?

If the server is returning something like that - it sounds like Karate is fine and you haven't sent the right request shape. Please work with the server-side team or someone familiar with the API to resolve that.

Otherwise please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue